# Потерявшие актуальность вопросы со временем

Tags: поддержка, предложение

Вот мне интересно, а как обстоят дела с "протухшими" вопросами и ответами.

Что я имею в виду: Допустим, есть вопрос или ответ, который в виду меняющихся условий либо потерял актуальность, либо стал неточным со временем. При этом у него много голосов "за".

Что делают с таким вопросом? Его исправляет кто-то авторитетный и все ему верят?

Наверное, не помешал бы механизм, который помечал бы такие ответы, как потенциально неверные или требующие исправления коллективно.

Comment: -1 за такой заголовок

Comment: @Igor а можно было бы внести правку

Answer (score 2):

Если вопрос отмечен как "общий", то вполне можно попробовать привести его к современным реалиям, но здесь надо учитывать ещё ситуацию, чтобы имеющиеся ответы не потеряли свою ценность при такой правке. Если, скажем речь о [c++] и в вопросе не было меток с указанием на заведомо старый стандарт на момент первичной публикации, то можно либо расширить такой вопрос довешиванием метки более свежего стандарта, например, [c++17], либо вовсе не трогать метки, ограничиваясь базовой [c++], и просто предоставить новый ответ, с учётом возможностей нового стандарта.

Если вопрос нельзя изменить так, чтобы ответы не потеряли своей ценности, то достаточно просто задать новый вопрос, добавив где-то по тексту ссылку на уже имеющийся.

Короче говоря, изменения/добавления надо вносить так, чтобы уровень знаний в текстах только повышался, ведь всегда кто-то может поставить себе старую и богом забытую версию продукта и попытаться решить какую-то задачу, руководствуясь ответом на SO. Конечно, могут быть частные случаи, когда задача опирается на какой-то внешний и закрытый сервис, ныне уже не функционирующий, но это всё частные случаи, которые можно рассмотреть отдельно.

Ну, а ещё для старых вопросов, к которым хорошо бы обновить ответы можно начать конкурс. Там даже причина подходящая имеется:

> [image: ответы устарели]

Answer (score 1):

Для начала, достаточно комментария под таким вопросом/ответом. Укажите что изменилось со временем. Автор скорее всего отреагирует и внесет ремарки или исправление в вопрос/ответ.

Если реакции нет, вы сами можете предложить правку. Постарайтесь отделить её от оригинального текста.

Также, можете дать свой ответ.

---

Ни одно из этих действий не будет бесполезным. Если у кого-то возникнет искомая проблема, он прочтет ваши комментарии/правки/ответ.